# Как описать документацию для PowerShell командлета на C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, документация

Не понимаю, откуда берёт документацию Get-Help, и как написать её для своих командлетов.

Comment: Кажется, нужно завести специальный xml с описанием, плюс добавлять аннотации/декораторы/как их там в шарпах называют.

Comment: Про XML: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/09/14/draft-creating-cmdlet-help/

Comment: Про декораторы: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/#seventh

Comment: Подробнее не могу ответить, потому что совсем не умею ни в С#, ни в PowerShell. Если за два дня ответ не дадут — маякните мне, открою конкурс с наградой. Вопрос интересный очень. :)

Comment: Действительно, по адресу https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/09/14/draft-creating-cmdlet-help/ то что нужно! Спасибо.

Comment: Здорово, что вы разобрались. Не могли бы вы тогда и ответ опубликовать? Он бы очень пригодился всем остальным, кто тоже эту тему осваивает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для бинарных командлетов запрограммированных на C#
Команда Get-Help ищет файл %moduleName%.dll-Help.xml в папке с самой скомпилированной сборкой модуля, содержащий документацию.
Есть не очень внятный набор [гайдов на msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/developer/help/writing-comment-based-help-topics), написан коряво и не объясняет как и что.
Есть [пошаговый тутор](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/09/14/draft-creating-cmdlet-help/) с примерами, из которого уже понятно как это делать.